# Android Location Update every 30 seconds

Tags: android, gps

If I determine the phone is active by reading the accelerometer, I want to update the location of the phone every 30 seconds. If after a while, I determine it's not moving, I stop the location updates.

Is it better to leave a LocationListener on during that time, or is it better to register a LocationListener every 30 seconds, get an update, and unregister?

For both methods, I would timeout after a while if I can't get a location update. I want to know which method is better in terms of both getting consistent updates and battery life.

And I'm trying to get updates through GPS satellites, not network, even though I know network is faster and less battery consuming, but I need to get it through satellites. Please keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, 30 seconds is to fast to get the listener, get an update, and shut it back down.   The only exception to that may be if you are willing to accept a very large accuracy number.   If you really need it every 30 seconds, leave it active, but the battery suffers.